# Comma separated string to List of int Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public partial class Source()
{
   ...............
   public string Assignees { get; set; }
   ...................
}
public partial class Destination
{
   ...............
   public List<int> Resources { get; set; }
   ...................
}
```

I'm mapping these classes like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.DestID, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.SrcID));//Automapper version 4.2.1.0
```

I'm getting the expected results for all the values,but the problem is with field **Assignees** in Source which is comma seperated string. It contains data like **"1,4,6,8"**

What i expect:

I want them to convert to **List of int** when mapping takes place.

Please provide any valueable inputs. Thank you.

Comment: That's string parsing, not mapping of objects or properties. There should be a way to specify a transformation function in the mapping

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos, this is an anti-pattern, because mappers are supposed to be dumb, and thus you might want to resist the temptation of putting too much logic inside them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a method to parse inside your mapper class:

```
using System.Linq;

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Resources, y => y.MapFrom(z => getAssignees(z.Assignees)));

private List<int> getAssignees(string model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return model.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This won't work. One cannot use `Cast` to convert a string to integer. Use `Select(int.Parse)` instead.

Comment: Good solution, Thanks. It works for me only when I made the method static.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to convert the `string` to a list of `int` I'd use `Linq`:

```
var str = "1,2,3,4";
var lst = str.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Than you can use the list in any way you want :)